# How can I get the same MD5 hash from both AS3 and VB.NET? Already have code, it doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, hash, md5

I need to generate a hash of a file in VB.NET on a server and send it to an AS3 client for validation against a file on the client. I chose MD5. I am using the builtin VB.NET MD5 hash and the hurlant MD5 hash on AS3. The results are different.

I am looking for a moderately reliable method of verifying the files are the same. Speed is as important as accuracy. I am open to other hashing algorithms which are at least as reliable/secure as MD5.

If there is a solution using what I have that would be great. If there is another way which works, that's OK too.

My VB Code looks like;

```
    Dim baFileData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFilePath))
    Dim strFileHash As String = GetHash(baFileData)

    Function GetHash(theInputBytes() As Byte) As String

        Using hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()    ' create hash object

            ' Convert to byte array and get hash
            Dim dbytes As Byte() =
                 hasher.ComputeHash(theInputBytes)

            ' sb to create string from bytes
            Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

            ' convert byte data to hex string
            For n As Integer = 0 To dbytes.Length - 1
                sBuilder.Append(dbytes(n).ToString("X2"))
            Next n

            Return sBuilder.ToString()
        End Using

    End Function
```

My AS3 code looks like this;

```
private function getFileMD5Hash(flLocalFile:File):String
{
    var strmInFile:FileStream = new FileStream();
    strmInFile.open(flLocalFile, FileMode.READ);
    var strFileData:String = strmInFile.readUTFBytes(strmInFile.bytesAvailable);
    strmInFile.close();
    var hash:IHash = Crypto.getHash("md5");
    var baFileData:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(strFileData));
    var baHash:ByteArray = hash.hash(baFileData);
    var strFileHash:String = Hex.fromArray(baHash);
    return strFileHash;
}
```

Comment: I now nothing about AS3 but it's always wrong to read in arbitrary bytes as UTF-8 encoded characters. The only thing you should read in with readUTFBytes are bytes that were written out with writeUTFBytes. I'm just guessing that these methods were designed to be interoperable with the Java methods of [DataInput/DataOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html).

Comment: Try reading the file as binary data **URLLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY**. It is not impossible that all these conversions you perform there, especially **String** ones, produce a different byte sequence than VB code gets. Just a guess though. Also, I'd start with test hashes of definitely identical and simple byte sequences (like 0,0,0,0 or 1,1,1,1) just to check if hash algorithms produce identical results.

Comment: @Organis I took your suggestion and tried a known string. Both routines provided the same results (I did need to .upper() the hex in AS3). I am now trying to understand how best to use URLLoader in my code.

Comment: @PaulStearns You can also read bytes with the FileStream class: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes()

Answer (score 1):

@Organis basically gave me the tools in his comments to solve the problem. My only reason for posting this as an answer is to show what the resulting code looks like.

If Organis posts an answer I will give it a vote.

The VB code remained the same.

The AS3 code changed to;

```
private function getFileMD5Hash(flLocalFile:File):String
{
    var strmInFile:FileStream = new FileStream();
    strmInFile.open(flLocalFile, FileMode.READ);
    var baFileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
    strmInFile.readBytes(baFileData);
    strmInFile.close();
    var hash:IHash = Crypto.getHash("md5");
    var baHash:ByteArray = hash.hash(baFileData);
    var strFileHash:String = Hex.fromArray(baHash).toUpperCase();
    return strFileHash;
}
```